# Geolocation in Java Jersey

Tags: java, apache, rest, tomcat, jersey

I would like to know if it is possible to call a method for every matching HTTP request.

My case:
I need to send geolocation data in http headers, I send the request, it matches a defined operation and at the same time my geolocation is updated.

I can easily replicate a method call for each method in each class, but I would rather find a more adequate way to solve this problem.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Jersey ResponseFilter.  Here is a very simple example that adds a static header to every outgoing request:

```
package my.package;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class SimpleFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{
  private static final String HEADER = "MyHeader";

  public SimpleFilter()
  {
  }

  @Override
  public ContainerResponse filter(final ContainerRequest request, final ContainerResponse response)
  {
    response.getHttpHeaders().add(HEADER, "MyValue");
    return response;
  }
}
```

You can access various information through the `request` and `response` parameters to the `filter` method.

You will need to add the filter through your web.xml file to activate it:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>my.package.SimpleFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```